# replace elements in a m x n array using list comprehension

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, list-comprehension

I have an array:

```
a = array([[1,2,3,1], [2,5,3,1], [0,0,0,0], [5,3,2,5]])
```

I want to iterate through the array, based off the last item in each row (0 or 1). If the last item in each row is 0, I want to change the 3 other items (only) in the row to np.nan.

For example:

```
a = array([[1,2,3,1], [2,5,3,1], [nan, nan, nan, 0], [5,3,2,5]])
```

I can do this using a for loop. i.e.:

```
for frames in range(len(a)):
    if a[frames][3] == 0:
        a[frames][0:2] = np.nan
```

Is there a more efficient way to do this using list comprehension? So far this is all I've come up with, but feel that it could be far more efficient:

```
a = np.array([[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] if frames[3] == 0 else frames[0:3] for frames in a])
```

As this will create an array of arrays, as well as crop the last column

Thanks in advance!

Comment: BTW `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan] = [np.nan] * 3`

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you don't need a list comprehension. Use [`indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

```
>>> a = np.array([[1,2,3,1], [2,5,3,1], [0,0,0,0], [5,3,2,5]], dtype=float)
>>> a[a[:,-1] == 0, 0:3] = np.nan

array([[  1.,   2.,   3.,   1.],
       [  2.,   5.,   3.,   1.],
       [ nan,  nan,  nan,   0.],
       [  5.,   3.,   2.,   5.]])
```

---

If you have a dict of these arrays, just index each of them

```
for a in data.values():
    a[a[:,-1] == 0, 0:3] = np.nan
```

Comment: if this array was part of a dictionary, could you then use the same indexing externally on a dictionary? e.g.

data = {a = np.array([[1,2,3,1],[3,1,2,1],[0,0,0,0],[2,4,7,1]]), b = np.array([[2,4,1,1],[0,0,0,0],[6,3,2,1],[5,2,3,1]])}

so that it woulr return: 

data = {a = np.array([[1,2,3,1],[3,1,2,1],[nan,nan,nan,0],[2,4,7,1]]), b = np.array([[2,4,1,1],[nan,nan,nan,0],[6,3,2,1],[5,2,3,1]])}
?

Comment: @NevPires yes.. just iterate and index each of the values

Comment: Thanks for your help! One other question, what does changing the dtype to float do?

Comment: @NevPires its just that if the dtype is integer, an exception might be raised when trying to assign `np.nan`. which is a float, to it